# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden during upload video in youtube from c#

Tags: c#, youtube-api

i am trying to upload video in youytube from my c# project
here is my design page

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="upload" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
```

here is my code behind

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
YouTubeModel youtubeModel;
YouTubeRequestSettings settings;
YouTubeRequest request;
string devkey = "my dev key";
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.FileName);
fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + filename);
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + filename;
string filepath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("youtube", "my clientid", devkey);
request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);
settings.Timeout =  int.MaxValue;
Video video = new Video();
video.Title = "Sample Video Title";
video.Description = "Sample Video Description";
video.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Comedy", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
video.Keywords = "Comedy";
video.Private =false;
video.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(filepath, "video/quicktime");
Video createdVideo = request.Upload(video);
}
```

i have used namespaces like that

```
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.YouTube;
using Google.GData.Extensions.MediaRss;
using Google.YouTube;
```

i already installed google Api v3 and i already generated ClientId key and Developer key 
what is the probelm??i have already searched in google but unable to get proper solution..what should i do for solving this problem??can anyone help me please???

Comment: If that's your real developer key, i would remove it...

Comment: yes it is real developer key ok i am deleting right now..but what is the problem??

Comment: The problem is someone else using it and maybe causing it to be cancelled for example for exceeding the quota

Comment: I've never done such a thing using C# but the error tell enough: You're not allowed to upload videos using API. Why? That's what you need to figure out. I think that you'll need to authenticate/authorize the API using oAuth flow, so that you'll have the token to perform this kind of operation.